# Why Html.TextBox is rendering field with date validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I am rendering out a DateTime field from my view model into two separate form fields (Date and Time). I have this line of code in my view:

```
@Html.TextBox("EndTime.Date", Model.EndTime.ToShortDateString())
```

which renders as:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." 
 data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="StartTime_Date"
 name="StartTime.Date" type="text" value="29/09/2012">
```

- Why is this input field having the data-* attributes added to it?
- Why does it even think it is a date?

An interesting side-effect of this unexpected validation is it causes the field to be validated as a date (which is what I want by coincidence), but jquery is deciding to use the **wrong date format** so I get the error:

> "The field Date must be a date."

---

**UPDATE:**
Turns out the "wrong date format" error was caused by a bug in Chrome. Because the JQuery Validation library validates a date by creating a new `Date()`, and because Chrome always seems to parse dates as en-US (totally ignoring the locale /language settings) it was failing when I put in en-UK dates.

Comment: Looking at the MVC source code, it appears to be taking action based on the field name. Investigation continues....

Comment: I have a feeling this is to do with the model prefix "." which I am using in the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this input field having the data-* attributes added to it?

Because you have enabled unobtrusive validation in your application. As default, the MVC validation system enables client-side validations of both required & datatype for value types(integer, datetime).

> Why does it even think it is a date?

When you pass a string to the `Html.TextBox` helper method it checks if the `Model` contains any property with that name and in your case the `Model` has a property with name `EndTime` and which is of type `DateTime`.

You are passing `EndTime.Date` that still represents the type `DateTime`(`DateTime` has a property `Date` which is of type `DateTime` contains only the date component) and so the two validations are enabled by MVC.

I would suggest you two create two different properties to store the date and time.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you may get unwanted validation fields even if you haven't explicitly added a validation attribute to that property.

You can disable that by adding this in your Application_Start():

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Additionally, what may fix your problem is that your property Model.EndTime should allow nulls:

```
DateTime? EndTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues when you use form names that are the same as the Model object... the form associates it with the Model automatically.

If you are planning to process the Date/Time values yourself after form submission you could create fields on your Model

```
private string _endDate;
public string EndDate 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_endDate == null)
                _endDate = EndTime.ToShortDateString();

            return _endDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _endDate = value;
        }
    }
```

And then use EndDate as your textbox field, or even use TextBoxFor and map it to your model. You can process the data afterwards in the post or in the set accessor.